# Where can I find archived traffic information for Swedish trains?

Tags: trains, sweden, delays

At the [Swedish Trafikverket website](http://trafikinfo.trafikverket.se/LIT/#url=Tagtrafiken/Taginfo&func=ts&value=94), I can find *current* times for trains by train numbers.
Like this, I can tell whether a train is running late. However, they only show today, perhaps yesterday and tomorrow for overnight trains.  [Swedish SJ](http://www.sj.se/sj/jsp/polopoly.jsp?d=21242&a=172166&l=sv) publish reliability statistics, but only by month and train category. For planning purposes ("do I take the bet for the train to be less than 1 hour late"), I'd be quite interested in looking through the exact delays for a specific train number for the past couple of weeks.

Is there any (probably unofficial) website archiving the information available on a daily basis at Trafikverket, so that users can find (recent) historical delay information for a specific train number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found [Senatåg](http://senatag.se/) which, as the name implies, lists late trains in Sweden. The user interface should be fairly self-descriptive. You can specify destinations, time period (what you are actually looking for) and minimum late time. Not sure if you can export the data to perform statistical analysis (if that's what your thing), but there seems to be an [API](http://api.senatag.se/) in beta that spews out JSON. Documentation is in Swedish, though.

[image]

Other possibilities are [Tåg.info](http://t%C3%A5g.info/) (with an å in the domain name) and [Tågtider.net](http://tagtider.net/)

Comment: Nice. Mini-review: Senatåg has some usability issues for night trains due to inconsistent train numbers during the night, but searching between two early morning stations resolves that. Tåg.Info misses delays for the same reason with no clear workaround. Can't find any historical info on Tågtider.net. The night-train problem is that if a night train is very late, it gets a new number and a morning train with the night trains number runs according to the night trains timetable. Consequently, the night train appears on time when it's actually 4+ hours late!

Comment: @gerrit: it would be interesting to see a more in-depth analysis and comparison between these services if you have the time to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no other source then the ones mentioned above. I guess that Senatåg.se is the best fit for you right now.

PS. We keep track of all changes in real-time and store it for eventual later use. I don't have any endpoints in place for returning the data you request at this point. Send me a message/tweet/email for more info. DS.

Comment: @ptzon - welcome to Travel.SE.  We do recommend you read our [faq] before posting.  One thing we focus on in particular (and on all SE sites) is: "Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, so be it...".  It's already been flagged, and your answer doesn't seem to add much aside from self promotion.  I'd consider rewording it to be more useful to avoid further downvotes.

Comment: @MarkMayo my fault - I asked ptz0n to comment since he really knows this stuff.

Comment: @MarkMayo I cannot upvote your comment. Thanks for your welcome and I have removed the reference to our project.